# MySQL - select rows where count in joined table equals 1

Tags: mysql, select, count

I need to select the rows from table "web_users" only if rows of another joined table called "web_users_branches" equals to 1.

What I have now:

```
SELECT id, code from web_users 
JOIN
(
SELECT client_code
  FROM web_users_branches
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
) as t2
ON web_users.code = t2.client_code;
```

I get empty result.

Database example:

Web Users table:

```
id code
1  0001
2  0002
3  0003
```

Web Users Branches table:

```
id  client_code
1   0001
2   0001
3   0002
4   0003
5   0003
```

Now after this query I should get only the user which client_code is 0002, because all the other user client_code count is not equal to 1 (there is x2 0003 and x2 0001). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want a `group by` in the subquery:

```
SELECT u.id, u.code 
FROM web_users u JOIN
     (SELECT client_code
      FROM web_users_branches
      GROUP BY client_code
      HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
     ) c
     ON u.code = c.client_code;
```

Comment: Why so complicated? You can just join and restrict the result set `having count(*) = 1`

Comment: @Psi . . . (1) Because this isn't complicated.  (2) This works even when `web_users` has duplicates.

Comment: (2) is true. (1) is maybe subject to a personal opinion, but I try to avoid sub-selects as much as i can.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, code 
FROM web_users_branches as t1
JOIN  web_users as t2
ON t2.code = t1.client_code
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

should work. After an inner join, you only get a single row when both(!) tables have exactly one record in the beginning.

Comment: Although this answer does not work generally (because it fails when `web_users` has duplicates), it definitely does not deserve a down vote.

Comment: It fails if web_users has duplicates, that's true, but that scenario was not given in the question. My goal was to avoid the sub-select.